# how do i run valgrind to a process which has super user bit on?

Tags: linux, memory, valgrind, setuid

I am running valgrind as follows:-

/usr/local/bin/valgrind "process_name"

After excecution its giving me following error

```
==21731==
==21731== Warning: Can't execute setuid/setgid executable: 
==21731== Possible workaround: remove --trace-children=yes, if in effect
==21731==
valgrind: "process name": Permission denied
```

My valgrind permission is as follows :-
-r-sr-xr-x /usr/local/bin/valgrind

My process permission is as follows:- 
-r-sr-xr-x  "process_name"

Platform : Linux VMLINUX3 2.6.9-78.0.22.ELsmp(RHEL)

Valgrind version: valgrind-3.5.0

Any help on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perpetual problem for people who develop FUSE file systems. [This link may help](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517110453/http://www.nabble.com/valgrind-and-fuse-file-systems-td13112112.html) (it's quite literally too much to consolidate in a single answer). The work-around involves a just-in-time replacement of fusermount, and (depending), some additional options to valgrind to prevent it from tracing children.

In fact, if you run my FS under valgrind, you get this output (yes, enough people had that problem that I actually detected valgrind on start up and displayed the link):

```
root@tower:~ # valgrind xsfs /xs
==9479== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==9479== Copyright (C) 2002-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9479== Using LibVEX rev 1884, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==9479== Copyright (C) 2004-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==9479== Using valgrind-3.4.1, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==9479== Copyright (C) 2000-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9479== For more details, rerun with: -v
==9479==
******** Valgrind has been detected by xsfs
******** If you have difficulties getting xsfs to work under Valgrind,
******** see the following thread:
******** http://www.nabble.com/valgrind-and-fuse-file-systems-td13112112.html
******** Sleeping for 5 seconds so this doesn't fly by ....
```

The *easiest* thing to do is all of your debugging in a disposable VM running as root, where you can just ditch the setuid bit, and be done with it. Make sure you test *your* code to not have any leaks or violations, its easy enough to test any linked library code not using fuse. Hand your build off 'valgrind-clean' and note that you've done so in the documentation.

Then, grab some bits out of `valgrind/valgrind.h` to detect it, and show a short message for those that go ahead and run it anyway. Hacks to work around it require root cooperation, and quite frankly, are much easier done in a sandbox just as well.

It's also easy enough to refuse to run under valgrind with the setuid bit on, showing a helpful message for people to turn it *off* if they really want to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose most simple answer would be to remove setuid/setgid bit while debugging. Of course if the program really needs root privileges you will have to probably run valgrind as root or since valgrind itself seems to be setuid just chown it to root:root. If you execute valgrind after that it will have root privileges (and so will it's children - debugged processes).

You should then be able to run valgrind on that application.

Just be careful, because you will be introducing a BIG security hole in your system. Safer solution would be to create special group only for users that should be able to run (setuid) valgrind and go from there...

Comment: If only it was that simple in all cases. FUSE relies on a setuid helper, which can't be un-set by underpriv users for debugging, so its extremely difficult to detect memory leaks in FUSE file systems. However, good answer for the topic at hand, sorry to get off on a tangent, this is one of my daily frustrations :)

Comment: True, as (almost) always there are exceptions, but generally this approach should do the trick.

Comment: just running valgrind as root didn't seem to be enough, but chown worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you tried running it with --trace-children=no?  If you have root access, there appears to be a workaround [here](http://old.nabble.com/valgrind-and-fuse-file-systems-td13112112.html).

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: The page can be found on the Wayback machine.  
https://web.archive.org/web/20100123225207/http://old.nabble.com/valgrind-and-fuse-file-systems-td13112112.html

Answer (score -1):

Run the valgrind command as root (or whoever the set-uid user is), then the program won't have to make use of setting the uid.

Comment: Sometimes, that's just not possible :)

Answer (score -1):

This happens even when things were run as root user :)
Best way is to change the perms to remove "s", and run

Comment: suid does not mean root. It means set user id where "user" can be anything.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all of the above suggestions but none of them really worked for me.

At the end i executed "sudo chmod 777  " and allowed all users on the system to read, write, and execute the file or directory. It is the most permissive setting, but it may not be recommended in all situations, as it can potentially create security vulnerabilities. It is generally advised to use more restrictive permissions whenever possible.

The command "sudo chmod 777  " is used to modify the permissions of a file or directory. Here is the breakdown of the command:
"sudo": It stands for "superuser do" and is used to execute the following command with administrative privileges. It allows you to perform actions that require root or superuser permissions.
"chmod": It is a command used to change the permissions of a file or directory.
"777": This is the permission setting that is being applied. Each digit in the three-digit number represents permissions for different user groups: owner, group, and others.

The first digit (7) represents the permissions for the owner of the file. In this case, the owner will have read, write, and execute permissions (4+2+1 = 7).

The second digit (7) represents the permissions for the group that the file belongs to. In this case, the group will also have read, write, and execute permissions.

The third digit (7) represents the permissions for others, i.e., users who are neither the owner nor in the group. In this case, others will have read, write, and execute permissions as well.